# Create two or more PDF - codeigniter with DOMPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, foreach, dompdf

I'm having problem to create more than one PDF. If I select 1 check to print the pdf it works fine but if I choose two or more then print only one of the selection.

In the view I have only a checkbox that pass o the controller the invoice id that I want to print in PDF.

The controller code is:

```
foreach ($this->input->post('check') as $key)
            {

                $invoiceData = array('invoice_number' => $key);
                $this->session->set_userdata($invoiceData);

                //verify the bank number
                $storeId = $this->session->userdata('user_store');
                $bank = $this->boletos->get_bank_store($storeId)->row();

                global $layout;
                if($bank->idBank == 1){
                    $layout = load_modulo('BankX', 'invoice_bankX');
                }

                $file_name = 'invoice-'.$key;
                pdf_create($layout, $file_name, TRUE);

            }
```

The pdf_create function:

```
function pdf_create($html, $filename = '', $stream = TRUE) {
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();

if ($stream) {
    $dompdf->stream($filename . ".pdf");
    //open on browser = $dompdf->stream($filename . ".pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
} else {

    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents('Brochure.pdf', $output);


    }
}
```

that's it - If I choose only one check it generates the PDF correctly. But if I choose two or more it print only one.
Any ideias on how to?

Comment: What happens when you try to render more than one PDF?

Comment: Hi, @BrianS - it generate only one PDF

Comment: Oh, I see the issue. You're streaming the PDF. It's true that you can only stream one PDF at a time. If you need to offer more you'll need to either have a list of links and generate them on the fly or pre-generate them and cache them on the server.

Comment: Thank you @BrianS by pointing the problem. Any suggestions on how to solve? I have not worked with DOMPDF before that so I can not imagine how to do or which search term to find a solution. tia

Answer (score 0):

First lets tweak your PDF creation function a bit:

```
function pdf_create($html, $stream = true) {
  require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->render();

  if ($stream) {
    $dompdf->stream($filename);
  } else {
    return $dompdf->output();
  }
}
```

Typically if you want to provide more than one PDF you'll need to render them separately and provide a link to each one. But if you're going to do that you might as well just provide a list of links and render each document as requested rather than pre-render them.

Unless you want to be able to provide some kind of batch processing. In which case something like the following would allow you to render the files. You just need to add some code to give the end user access:

```
foreach ($this->input->post('check') as $key) {
  $invoiceData = array('invoice_number' => $key);
  $this->session->set_userdata($invoiceData);

  //verify the bank number
  $storeId = $this->session->userdata('user_store');
  $bank = $this->boletos->get_bank_store($storeId)->row();

  global $layout;
  if ($bank->idBank == 1) {
    $layout = load_modulo('BankX', 'invoice_bankX');
  }

  $file_name = 'invoice-'.$key.'.pdf';
  $pdf = pdf_create($layout, $file_name, false);
  file_put_contents($file_name, $pdf);
}
```

To provide the list of links you could either record the filenames or, if you save the files to a per-user directory, read out the list of files.

If you want to be able to render all the selected documents and give them to the user at the same time you could render them and package the output in an archive such as a .zip file:

```
$zipfile = 'invoices.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipfile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($this->input->post('check') as $key) {
  $invoiceData = array('invoice_number' => $key);
  $this->session->set_userdata($invoiceData);

  //verify the bank number
  $storeId = $this->session->userdata('user_store');
  $bank = $this->boletos->get_bank_store($storeId)->row();

  global $layout;
  if ($bank->idBank == 1) {
    $layout = load_modulo('BankX', 'invoice_bankX');
  }

  $file_name = 'invoice-'.$key.'.pdf';
  $pdf = pdf_create($layout, $file_name, false);
  $zip->addFromString($file_name, $pdf);
}

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($zipfile).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfile));
readfile($zipfile);
```

(Forgive the lack of error checking, *which you should totally do*.)

Lastly, rather then rendering each document separately you could combine the output of each document into one large document, inserting page breaks or spacer pages between the documents:

```
$pages = array();
foreach ($this->input->post('check') as $key) {
  $invoiceData = array('invoice_number' => $key);
  $this->session->set_userdata($invoiceData);

  //verify the bank number
  $storeId = $this->session->userdata('user_store');
  $bank = $this->boletos->get_bank_store($storeId)->row();

  if ($bank->idBank == 1) {
    $pages[] = load_modulo('BankX', 'invoice_bankX');
  }
}
$layout = implode('<div style="page-break-before: always;"><div>', $pages);
pdf_create($layout, 'invoices.pdf', true);
```

Comment: Thank for your reply! I'm going to test this and return here to post results telling what happened. tia